# Sharepoint URL to search in list and create new input to search

Tags: list, search, search-results

I can't enable "Display search box", bacuse this button not isset in my Web Part steeing. I checked this, reading this [instruction](https://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2012/12/31/display-search-box-nowhere-to-be-found-in-a-sharepoint-2013-web-part/)

Now I write my input and code javascript to search in list:

Input and button to search:

```
   <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="search ..." onclick="this.value=&#39;&#39;"/>
   <i id="search-submit" class="material-icons">Szukaj</i> </div>
```

and code JS to search:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    function inputSearch() {
        var link = "";
        var el = document.querySelector("#search-submit");
        el.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var queryString = document.querySelector("#search-input").value;
            var location = "/Lists/test/calendar.aspx?u=#k=" + queryString;
            link = location;
            document.querySelector("#search-input").setAttribute("value", '');
            window.location.href = link;
            return;
        })
    }

    inputSearch();

    document.querySelector("#search-input").addEventListener("keydown", function(key) {
        console.log(key);
        if (key == 13) {
            document.querySelector("#search-submit").click();
        }
    })
})
```

**I don't know what is URL to search**, now I using:

`var location = "/Lists/test/calendar.aspx?u=#k=" + queryString;`

But JS return still all records from list, I need return only those records in which the query occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, read this [article](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/03/sharepoint-search-filter-or-sort-lists.html)  and [this article](https://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/filtering-listviews-with-url-query.html).
For example, I have address URL to my list:

`/Lists/test/calendar.aspx`

and now I must add to URL `FilterName` and `FilterMultiValue`:

```
?FilterName=name_column_where_you_want_search&FilterMultiValue=the_name_of_the_searched_value
```

My code look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    function inputSearch() {
        var link = "";
        var el = document.querySelector("#search-submit");
        el.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var queryString = document.querySelector("#search-input").value;
            var selected = document.querySelector("#select-list").value;

            var location = "/Lists/test/calendar.aspx?FilterName=" + selected + "&FilterMultiValue=*" + queryString + "*";
            link = location;
            document.querySelector("#search-input").setAttribute("value", '');
            window.location.href = link;
            return;
        })
    }

    inputSearch();

    document.querySelector("#search-input").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.key == 'Enter') {
            document.querySelector("#search-submit").click();
        }
    })
})
```